# How do I use next-i18next for translation in a normal component that is being used in pages directory files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-i18next, next-i18next

I'm using `next-i18next` for translation.

I have no problem of setting it up in files located in `pages` directory. This is what I have done:

```
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'

export const getServerSideProps = async ({locale}) => {
  const response = await API.get(getHomePageWidgetApi, {
    headers: {
      platform: "web"
    }
  });

  let homePageWidgets = response?.data;

  if(response?.code === 200) {
    return {
      props: {
        homePageWidgets,
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
          'common'
        ])),
    }
    }
  }

}
```

The problem happens when I need to do translation in files located in `components` directory. Those components are being used by files in `pages` directory.

This is what I have tried:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

function ArticleItemLists(props) {
    
    const { t } = useTranslation('common');
    
    return (
         <div className="btn_container">
                            <RightArrowWithBorder />
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                className="underline_ancer"
                                onClick={mixPanelTracking}
                            >
                                {/* {btnText || i18n.t('read_more_capital')} */}
                                {t('read_more_capital')}
                            </button>
                        </div>
    )

}
```

But, this gives me an error saying:

`TypeError: (0 , next_i18next__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.useTranslation) is not a function`

I don't know what I do now because I can't just use `serverSideTranslations` in normal components.